# Python array: get index by element value

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7

A have an array like this

```
{  
    "records":[  
        {  
            "domain":"example.com",
            "fqdn":"111",
        },
        {  
            "domain":"example.com",
            "fqdn":"2222",
        },
        {  
            "domain":"example.com",
            "fqdn":"333",
        },
    ],
}
```

How can I get index of element with fqdn == "333"?

Comment: I know, that I can use for, but I hope, that there is another way

Comment: I'm wondering why you need this index in the first place. Can you tell us more - most probably, there's a better way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension with `enumerate`:

```
[x for x, y in enumerate(data['records']) if y['fqdn'] == '333'][0]
```

You'd have to catch `IndexError` for the case where it didn't exist, though.

As suggested in the comments, you could avoid the issues of redundant lookups for duplicate target values, and catching `IndexError`, by using a generator and `next`:

```
next((x for x, y in enumerate(data['records']) if y['fqdn'] == '333'), None)
```

Comment: If there's more than one target value, your code will make redundant lookups.

Comment: You can also use a generator expr instead of a comp, `next((...), None)` thus avoiding an exception and the problem in the ^^^ comment.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you want something like this,

```
>>> d = {  
    "records":[  
        {  
            "domain":"example.com",
            "fqdn":"111",
        },
        {  
            "domain":"example.com",
            "fqdn":"2222",
        },
        {  
            "domain":"example.com",
            "fqdn":"333",
        },
    ],
}
>>> for i in d.values():
        for s,m in enumerate(i):
            if m['fqdn'] == "333":
                print(s)


2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
li = list(di['records'])
for x in li:
    for k, v in x.items():
        if v == '333':
            print k, v
```

Comment: Usually it is helpful to include some text which explains how the code answers the question or solves the problem in addition to bare code.